# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 14: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, shapefile

Im trying to export a shape file of a GeoDataFrame

`gdb.to_file(pth_info+'Barrio_Dptos.shp')`

The error is

**UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 14: ordinal not in range(256)**

Comment: `latin-1` isn't Unicode, it's a single-byte codepage that can only handle Western European text (Latin characters). Shapefile is an **ancient** format, from the DOS/dBase IV days when almost nobody thought about Unicode. Either GeoDataFrame can't work with Unicode or shapefiles don't allow Unicode at all

Comment: The character you postes id the [en-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) which looks like a normal dash but *isn't*. Was the text copy/pasted from some a web page perhaps? You could bypass the problem by removing the en-dash, or replacing it with a normal dash

Comment: I need to put the GeoDataFrame in QGIS. Which format do you recomend?

Comment: GeoPackage is a great format for this. A single SQLite-based file, containing all of data, metadata and spatial index. If GeoDataFrame uses GDAL/OGR under the hood, you should be able to change the extension to `.gpkg` and have it just work.

Comment: @AgustínJornet the easiest solution is to remove the non-ASCII character. You can't even type that character directly so where did it come from? A web page? Word document? How did you create the GeoDataFrame?

Comment: Saving it in ```.gpkg``` format has worked. The data came from the internet! Thank you all guys!